# How to prevent adb client from auto starting adb server?

Tags: android, adb

It seems like whenever adb client cannot communicate with adb server, it automatically starts it. Is there a way to prevent adb server from automatically starting like this?

Comment: That is the way adb is designed. Can you explain a bit more why you don't want adb server to be started?

Comment: I'm using another adb server and I don't want the default one started automatically since it will block the port

Comment: Then configure all your programs to use the ADB server you want to use. Some tool also respect the `ADB` environment variable (should point to the adb.exe to be used). Alternatively copy the one adb version to all locations where the other adb versions are saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify server address and if adb think it is not a local address, then adb won't start a local server.

Addresses start with "local" are considered as local address, but "127.0.0.1" is not.

So you can set `ADB_SERVER_SOCKET=127.0.0.1:5037` or `ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1` to prevent starting local server.

If you are interested in the detail, see `is_local_socket_spec` in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/adb/+/d7285b7cdd139ada5d662b5f3c1c5a4e16462299/socket_spec.cpp#128

Comment: You have to include the configuration file and the path of config file where you can set those values.